# CSS Button background image not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, jet

I have tried multiple sources online and ended up putting many things together. I know individually how they work but not sure what I do wrong here.

My CSS looks like this:

```
    .chatButton {
    position: fixed;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #888888;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    background-image: url('https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/chat-outline.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.chatButton:hover {background-color: #888888; bottom: 55px;}

.chatButton:active {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #888888;
}
```

And my html like this:

```
<oj-button class="chatButton" on-oj-action="[[openListener]]">

      </oj-button>
```

I am using oracle jet, but even if I remove oj-button and use a normal button I can't get the background image to show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid value for `background-image` - it should just have the url. Use the `background` shorthand if you're trying to set all those other properties in one declaration. (Also, have you expected in devtools to see if the rule is being applied?)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tLsvh6uk/1/ (quick answer) - gonna go in depth in a sec.

Comment: Get rid of  everything behind **url** and set them separately.

Comment: @Mike this indeed seems to be what I am looking for. I think the issue is on my end then because somehow although in the fiddle it looks fine, in my html/css it does not work i.e. no image shown.

Comment: @Vaggouras i am not familiar with `jet` if there could be anything with that. However the css and html part should work after that change.

Answer (score 1):

So i'm new to `oracle jet` but here is something i found:

There is some issues with using the `background-image` properties.

Here is some [Examples from oracle](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=imagecss&demo=clickable):

I found a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1n6ay04/2050/) with an example where `oracle jet` is used.

As you can see i added your button and the css. There i had the same issues with no image. Even after the css changes as listed in the comments.

With the changes from the `oracle example` i added a `span` inside the button and added this css:

```
.chatButton span{
  height:60%;
  content: url('https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/chat-outline.png');
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1n6ay04/2052/)

Comment: Great result. Still on my end I can't render it but I will need to find out why. Perhaps the ojet setup or something. Thanks though I will use it like that in terms of css code

Comment: Worked!! Can't thank you enough mate! :) wish I could upvote 124 times

Comment: Glad it worked for you :-) If it answers your question you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set all the properties of the background in one line you should use `background`, not `background-image`.

```
background: url('https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/chat-outline.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
```